# concat a char 2D array element and int in C++

Tags: c++, char, int, concatenation

I have a 2D char array,

```
static char a[25][25];
```

Consider the matrix filled with numbers. 
main code:

```
for(i=0;i<25;i++){
if(a[pos][pos]!='0'){
            strcpy(result,(char)i);
            strcat(a[pos][pos],result);
        }}
```

'pos' is a number that i generate. I want to concat an element of this, say a[i][j] with the integer 'i'. I tried a few posts from this site but they are still giving me different errors

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:214:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ [-fpermissive]
matrix.cpp:42:58: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:214:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ [-fpermissive]
```

I am a newbie. Could anyone please explain me where i am going wrong and whats the best method to solve it? Thank You.

Comment: Please provide some code, that will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to answer without more details, but here it goes..

Every element in your array (like a[i][j]) is of type `char`

This means it is basically a **single** character

You can't really concat an integer and place it inside a single `char`, for starters, the integer itself is larger (byte-wise) than your entire `char` so obviously it can't fit in there

Maybe you're really trying to make every element in your array a **string** (multiple chars) and not a single char. If this is the case, every element will probably need to be of type `char*`, so you'll get:

```
static char* a[25][25];
```

If you do this, you will need to allocate your strings (using `new` or `malloc`) and process them with the various string-handling functions of the standard library (which accept `char*` as arguments). If I'm guessing correctly according to the errors you're getting, that's what you're trying to do...

Comment: Yes. I tried as u have suggested and used
'strcpy(result,(char)i); strcat(a[pos][pos],result);' where result is a char array of 100. but now it says 'invalid conversion from int to char*'

Comment: Take a look at a function called `itoa` which converts integers into char * http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/

Comment: also, make sure you allocate buffers of memory to hold your char * with malloc or new before placing information there. here is a related code example: http://www.cprogramming.com/snippets/source-code/dynamically-allocating-a-multidimensional-array